# SQL 2000 - Returning from a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

I'm writing a stored procedure. This procedure has a case where if it is met, I want to stop executing the procedure and return -1. How do I do this? Currently, I'm trying the following:

```
IF @result <> 1
BEGIN
  SELECT -1                 
END
```

However, SELECT is not a typical "return". As you can imagine I spend most of my time in code which is why i'm looking for something like a "return".

Thank you,

Comment: Been a long time since I worked on SQL 2000 - I presume RETURN -1 is invalid syntax back in the 2000 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IF @result <> 1
BEGIN
  RETURN -1                 
END
SELECT * FROM bla
RETURN 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IF @result <> 1
BEGIN
  SELECT -1          
  RETURN       
END
```

does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
IF @result <> 1
BEGIN
  RETURN -1                 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

[RETURN (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx)

> Exits unconditionally from a query or
>   procedure. RETURN is immediate and
>   complete and can be used at any point
>   to exit from a procedure, batch, or
>   statement block. Statements that
>   follow RETURN are not executed.
>
> When used with a stored procedure,
>   RETURN cannot return a null value. If
>   a procedure tries to return a null
>   value (for example, using RETURN
>   @status  when @status is NULL), a
>   warning message is generated and a
>   value of 0 is returned

.

It is a common convention to return zero `0` when everything is fine, a negative value when there is a soft error (like validation or user warning) and a positive value for a hard error, like insert failed, etc.

```
...

IF @result!=1
BEGIN
  RETURN -1 --there was an error!          
END

....

RETURN 0  --everything is fine
```